# How to change the color of drop down list of select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 drop down list for selection of product in the stock. I want to change the color of drop list according to the availability of stock. If stock is not available color of option should be red. otherwise green. The response from server side contains a data attribute named stock which holds the quantity of stock. If stock is greater than zero option color should be green otherwise red.

```
$('#aid').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select product ',
    minimumInputLength:2,
    cache:false,
    ajax: {
        url: 'definesale.php?aid=true',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 50,
        processResults: function (data) {
            //response is ["id"=>2,"text"=>"product","stock"=>2]
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: false
    }
});
```

Comment: i think you can create a class `.stock-high` then use your colors there and add the class to the products when rendered. That would mean you need to do a console and see which elements to target when coloring

Comment: Will you please share any example?